# mpich2 visual studio 2013 linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, mpich

I want to use mpi in c++ way, so I have code of cxxpi.cxx from mpich2 examples:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double f(double);

double f(double a) {
    return (4.0 / (1.0 + a*a));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n, myid, numprocs, i;
    double PI25DT = 3.141592653589793238462643;
    double mypi, pi, h, sum, x;
    double startwtime = 0.0, endwtime;
    int  namelen;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI::Init(argc, argv);
    numprocs = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
    myid = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
    MPI::Get_processor_name(processor_name, namelen);

    cout << "Process " << myid << " of " << numprocs << " is on " <<
        processor_name << endl;

    n = 10000;          /* default # of rectangles */
    if (myid == 0)
        startwtime = MPI::Wtime();

    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0);

    h = 1.0 / (double) n;
    sum = 0.0;
    /* A slightly better approach starts from large i and works back */
    for (i = myid + 1; i <= n; i += numprocs) {
        x = h * ((double) i - 0.5);
        sum += f(x);
    }
    mypi = h * sum;

    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Reduce(&mypi, &pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0);

    if (myid == 0) {
        endwtime = MPI::Wtime();
        cout << "pi is approximately " << pi << " Error is " <<
            fabs(pi - PI25DT) << endl;
        cout << "wall clock time = " << endwtime - startwtime << endl;
    }

    MPI::Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I set properties of my VS2013 project:

1. Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories > (added path) **"C:\Program Files\MPICH2\include"**
2. Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories > (added path)
   **"C:\Program Files\MPICH2\lib"**
3. Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > (added lib) **"mpi.lib"**
4. Properties > Platform > (setted to) **Active(x64)**

And I've got **unresolved reference** linker errors. The code of cpi.c with the same properties compiles with no problems. I think the problem is in libs which linker needs, but I tried to find a combination of them, but it didn't solve the problem. MPICH2 has such libs: cxx.lib, fmpich2.lib, fmpich2g.lib, irlog2rlog.lib, mpe.lib, mpi.lib, rlog.lib, TraceInput.lib. How to make the program work correct?

Comment: And the linker errors are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more additional dependency - cxx.lib

This library contains all necessary bindings for c++.

You may just look into MPICH2/examples/cxxpi.vcproj to discover that this library is needed to be linked.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already tried this but I had no result because I changed settings of wrong configuration combination. I had configuration "Release, Active(x64)" but in project properties I had "Debug, Active(x64)". I hadn't notice if you change some of configs either "Configuration" or "Platform" then you've got different version of project settings.